# Does mongodb lock between bulk groups?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, locking, bulkupdate

Given a collection containing documents of the following format:

```
{ 
  name:String,
  members: [ { name:String, type: String } ]
}
```

Let's say I have a mongodb bulk operation, containing two operations:

- A) for a list of given documents, remove all members with type 'x'
- B) for that same list of given documents, add a set of members with type 'x'

The question is: will mongodb lock the documents in question between A and B? So that no modification to 'members' of the targeted documents can take place by other processes between A and B?

Comment: No it won't. By default, MongoDB operations will be atomic _per document_, and not within a group of documents (which is what a bulk operation is). What you're describing is a feature of transactions, which is a new MongoDB 4.0 feature. I'm not sure if Spring supports this yet.

Comment: Why mention this as a comment? It is a clear answer....

Comment: Sure I can put it up as an answer.

Comment: Thx. That is the whole point of SO :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't. By default, MongoDB operations will be atomic per document, and not within a group of documents (which is what a bulk operation is).

To quote from the [Atomicity and Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/) page:

> In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single document.

Also:

> When a single write operation (e.g. db.collection.updateMany()) modifies multiple documents, the modification of each document is atomic, but the operation as a whole is not atomic.

MongoDB 4.0, however, supports [multi-document ACID transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions) with some restrictions, such as it supports it only on replica sets, and the overall data in a transaction cannot exceed 16 MB.

Regarding Spring, MongoDB 4.0 transactions is supported in the Lovelace release ([DATAMONGO-1920](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1920)). There are examples in this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/28/hands-on-mongodb-4-0-transactions-with-spring-data) by Pivotal.